# How to fetch elements from NSArray in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, mkmapview

I'm using a bus timetable API and want to display the nearby bus stop according to user current location. I've already got the the JSON response through url and parsed JSON to NSArray. The NSArray looks like this.

```
{
    result =         {
        distance = "0.00003292029";
        lat = "-37.92091";
        "location_name" = "Monash Medical Centre/Clayton Rd ";
        lon = "145.120682";
        "route_type" = 2;
        "stop_id" = 16518;
        suburb = Clayton;
        "transport_type" = bus;
    };
    type = stop;
},
    {
    result =         {
        distance = "0.00003728643";
        lat = "-37.92227";
        "location_name" = "Monash Surgical Private Hospital/291 Clayton Rd ";
        lon = "145.1202";
        "route_type" = 2;
        "stop_id" = 24348;
        suburb = Clayton;
        "transport_type" = bus;
    };
    type = stop;
},
    {
    result =         {
        distance = "0.00003804303";
        lat = "-37.9230766";
        "location_name" = "Clayton Railway Station/Clayton Rd ";
        lon = "145.120209";
        "route_type" = 2;
        "stop_id" = 22809;
        suburb = Clayton;
        "transport_type" = bus;
    };
    type = stop;
},
    {
    result =         {
        distance = "0.00003976311";
        lat = "-37.9186172";
        "location_name" = "Monash Specialist Centre/Clayton Rd ";
        lon = "145.121033";
        "route_type" = 2;
        "stop_id" = 22807;
        suburb = Clayton;
        "transport_type" = bus;
    };
    type = stop;
},
    {
    result =         {
        distance = "0.00004085229";
        lat = "-37.9186478";
        "location_name" = "Dixon St/Clayton Rd ";
        lon = "145.120911";
        "route_type" = 2;
        "stop_id" = 13889;
        suburb = Clayton;
        "transport_type" = bus;
    };
    type = stop;
}
```

)

My question is how to get the latitude and longitude from this NSArray. I wrote these code but it returns  nil.

```
    NSMutableArray *coordinateLatit = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (int i = 0; i<nearbyStop.count; i++) {
    NSString *latit = [[nearbyStop objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"lat"];
    if(latit == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"there is no data");
    }
    else
    {
    [coordinateLatit addObject:latit];
    }
}
```

And also i want to display the stops(use longitude&latitude from NSArray) on MKMapView, how should i manage to implement the MKLocalSearchRequest
Appreciate it if anyone can help me!

Comment: how did you product the listing of data that *looks like this* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code overlooked the extra nested `result` level.

```
NSMutableArray *coordinateLatit=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for(NSDictionary *d in nearbyStop)
{
    NSString    *latit=d[@"result"][@"lat"];

    if(lat) [coordinateLatit addObject:latit];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It's working now! But why the method returns me a NSDictionary type. In my nearby method, the return type is NSArray..

Comment: Look at the JSON. It is an array of dictionaries. Each dictionary contains a `result` key, with another dictionary as value. And inside that dictionary you find the `lat` key. The `for` line in above code runs though the outer array, and gives you the dictionary in `d`. And d[@"result"][@"lat"] drills down into that dictionary.

Comment: BTW if there would be never any missing keys (result or lat), you could do everything in a single line: `NSArray coordinateLatit=[nearbyStop valueForKeyPath: @"result.lat"];`.

Answer (score 0):

you miss a level of the json response, it should be

```
for (Stop *stop in nearbyStop) {
    NSString *latit = [[stop objectForKey:@"result"] objectForKey:@"lat"];
    if(latit == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"there is no data");
    }
    else
    {
        [coordinateLatit addObject:latit];
    }
}
```

Comment: thx for your answer, but it seems doesn't work when i changed to objectForKey:@"result" inside the brackets.  It says no visible @interface for declares the selector

Comment: what about valueForKeyPath:@"result.lat"

Answer (score 0):

```
-(id) doApiCall:(NSString*)apiCall useCache:(BOOL)useCache
{


   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", mBaseURL, [MapViewController signApiCall:apiCall]]];

id response = [self httpWrapper:url];
    NSLog( @"%@", response );
return response;
}



-(id) httpWrapper:(NSURL*)url

{
    __block id response = nil;

void (^doStuff)() = ^void()
{
    int retry = 3;
    NSError * error;


    while( retry > 0) {
        NSData * data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                                                 cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                                             timeoutInterval:600] returningResponse:nil error:&error ];

        if( data != nil )
        {
            response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
            if( response != nil)
                retry = 0;
        }

        if(data == nil || response == nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"Bad response %@", url);
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
            --retry;
        }
    }
};


    doStuff();


    return response;
}

-(NSArray*) nearby:(CLLocation*)location
{

        return [self doApiCall:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/v2/nearme/latitude/%f/longitude/%f?limit=5", location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude]];

}
```

Here is the code i'm using to call the API. I use id for the response from url request. so does nearby method returns NSArray type?